# Check engine light on at 140km/h

Tags: engine, cel, alfa-romeo

I just bought an used Alfa Romeo 147 1.6TS 120cp. At high speed like 140km/h the car doesn't go more fast and the engine light is showing. After some  short time the check engine is no more there. I noticed that the car is shaking a bit when I'm in park. Is this a bad spark plug?

Comment: Have you read the codes? That might point to turbo or something...

Comment: Read codes on the vehicle. Sounds like it could be ignition or fueling.

Comment: @SolarMike TS comes from Twin Spark. It has no turbo. I haven't read the codes.

Comment: @yollooool The car is making a lot of white smoke. Doesn't this mean that there is oil on the bad spark plug?

Comment: White smoke usually means coolant. If it was oil on a plug, you would see blue smoke.